# Retrieving the details of the current online user in firebase database, It keeps returning null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Please I am unable to retrieve the details of the current online user in firebase. This is my code but I dont really know what is the issue. The data keeps returning null even when the database reference is correct.When I login using the firebaseAuth that signin user with email and password, it sign me in correctly but can't get the data of the current online user which is my name,phone,email,address,sid etc.

```
private DatabaseReference sellerRef;
private FirebaseUser currentUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String sellerPresent = currentUser.getUid();

Then i initalize the FirebaseDatabase in the oncreate like this

sellerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sellers");

sellerRef.child(sellerPresent)
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                //SellersModel sellersModel = snapshot.getValue(SellersModel.class);
                sName = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                sEmail = snapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                sPhone = snapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
                sAddress = snapshot.child("address").getValue().toString();
                sid = snapshot.child("sid").getValue().toString();
                Log.d("Seller","the seller name"+sName);
                Log.d("Seller","the seller email"+sEmail);
                Log.d("Seller","the seller phone"+sPhone);
                Log.d("Seller","the seller Address"+sAddress);
                Log.d("Seller","the seller id"+sid);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("Seller","Error message"+error);
        }
    });
```

This is the database

```
{
  "Admin" : {
    "08167988220" : {
      "name" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "password" : "adminmet",
      "phone" : "08167988220"
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "08167988220" : {
      "Security Questions" : {
        "question1" : "Pounded yam",
        "question2" : "Madrid"
      },
      "address" : "New Airport, Calabar South",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-app-c7f6b.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Pictures%2F08167988220.jpg?alt=media&token=46998a82-815e-49f6-8299-cf507aa3b55c",
      "name" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "password" : "meteorologist",
      "phone" : "08167988220",
      "phoneOrder" : "08167988220"
    }
  },
  "sellers" : {
    "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3" : {
      "address" : "New Airport",
      "email" : "elijah@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "password" : "22446688",
      "phone" : "08167988220",
      "sid" : "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot see it.

Comment: I have edited it. I want to retrieve all those data for each current online user in that seller reference

Comment: `xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3` is the UID of the logged-in user?

Comment: You have a spelling/capitalization mistake between the code and the JSON: `sellers` vs `Sellers`. When the two don't match exactly, the `onDataChange` will be called with an empty snapshot.

Comment: Such a silly mistake, thanks so much @FrankvanPuffelen. That was the issue, now it has been resolved

Comment: It happens to many of us all the time, so I'm glad you got it fixed  --- I voted to close your question as a typo.